# Wordpress - page content not displaying

Tags: php, wordpress

I created a Wordpress theme with bootstrap 3 using the following instructions:

http://www.creativewebdesign.ro/en/blog/wordpress/create-a-responsive-wordpress-theme-with-bootstrap-3-header-and-footer/

The content isn't displaying on any pages. I'm not sure if there is a problem with the container div:

http://www.dawaf.co.uk/creative-mapping/

The test text doesn't show up when I do view the page source.

**index.php**

```
<?php
/**
 * The main template file.
 *
 * This is the most generic template file in a WordPress theme and one of the
 * two required files for a theme (the other being style.css).
 * It is used to display a page when nothing more specific matches a query.
 * For example, it puts together the home page when no home.php file exists.
 *
 * Learn more: http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy
 *
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage Wp_Bootstrap
 * @since Wp Bootstrap 1.0
 */

    // Gets header.php
    get_header();

<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

<?php the_title(); ?></h1>  
        <div class="entry">
            <?php the_content(); ?>
        </div><!-- entry -->
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>

    // Gets footer.php
    get_footer(); 
?>
```

**page.php**

```
<?php
/**
 * The main template file.
 *
 * This is the most generic template file in a WordPress theme and one of the
 * two required files for a theme (the other being style.css).
 * It is used to display a page when nothing more specific matches a query.
 * For example, it puts together the home page when no home.php file exists.
 *
 * Learn more: http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy
 *
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage Wp_Bootstrap
 * @since Wp Bootstrap 1.0
 */

    // Gets header.php
    get_header();

    // Gets footer.php
    get_footer(); 
?>
```

Comment: "It is working correctly" can't be in the same sentence with "content isn't displaying on any pages".

Comment: I amended the question

Comment: There's **no** content. This is definitely not a Bootstrap issue. You should look in your Wordpress code.

Comment: Maybe you could share your `page.php` code.

Comment: I think you forgot something in your code or there's something wrong. Could you please show to us that we can help you?

Comment: I have added the index.php and header.php above

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I can't see `<?php the_content(); ?>` in your code. This is needed to display the content. Here you can see the [Wordpress page about the_content](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_content). So add `<?php the_content(); ?>` to your `index.php` or rather to your `page.php` file or there where you want to display your content.

**EDIT:**

You also can look at the other themes in your wordpress folder (twentyten etc.). There you can see how `<?php the_content(); ?>` is used.

**EDIT 2:**

I forgot to say this. You have to add this to your file, too:

```
<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

<?php the_title(); ?></h1>  
        <div class="entry">
            <?php the_content(); ?>
        </div><!-- entry -->
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

This will check if you got any posts or pages. If yes, it will display it, if no, it won't display anything. Put this to your `index.php` between `<?php get_header(); ?>` and `<?php get_footer(); ?>`.

**EDIT 3:**

I've seen your edit in your question. And I've seen the error. You opened the `<?php` tag twice. You can go this way:

```
<?php
/**
 * The main template file.
 *
 * This is the most generic template file in a WordPress theme and one of the
 * two required files for a theme (the other being style.css).
 * It is used to display a page when nothing more specific matches a query.
 * For example, it puts together the home page when no home.php file exists.
 *
 * Learn more: http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy
 *
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage Wp_Bootstrap
 * @since Wp Bootstrap 1.0
 */

    // Gets header.php
    get_header();
?>

<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

<?php the_title(); ?></h1>  
        <div class="entry">
            <?php the_content(); ?>
        </div><!-- entry -->
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php // Gets footer.php
get_footer(); 
?>
```

This code should be in your `index.php` and in your `page.php`.

Comment: I tried adding it to the index.php but it doesn't seem to be working. Do I need to place it somewhere in particular?

Comment: Think where your content should be displayed. On your website I think it should be displayed between `<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">` and `<div class="well well-sm">`. Is that right? Or where should the content be displayed?

Comment: Yes that's right. So I need to add the <?php the_content(); ?> inbetween get_header(); and get_footer(); in the index.php. Is that correct?

Comment: Should be correct. If not, try to add it to your `page.php`, too. Is the code above your whole code in your `index.php` file?

Comment: Yes that's everything. I don't have a page.php because the instructions I followed above didn't mention it. Adding <?php the_content(); ?> has broken the site - if you refresh the header & footer are no longer visible.

Comment: Create an `page.php` file and paste the same in it as you have in your `index.php` file. See here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Pages. I'm sorry I forgot to say something, I will make an edit - look at it

Comment: I have taken <?php the_content(); ?> out of index.php and created a page.php file and copied the same from index. I will wait for your edit.

Comment: Yes I did thanks. I added the edit to index.php but still no luck. If I add it to page.php too it breaks the site.

Comment: Can you please add your `index.php` and `page.php` you have now to your question?

Answer (score 0):

Use this code in page.php:

```
<div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
<?php if ( is_front_page() ) { ?>
     <h2 class="entry-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
<?php } else { ?>
    <h1 class="entry-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
<?php } ?>

     <div class="entry-content">
       <?php the_content(); ?>
      <?php wp_link_pages( array( 'before' => '<div class="page-link">' . __( 'Pages:', 'twentyten' ), 'after' => '</div>' ) ); ?>
    <?php edit_post_link( __( 'Edit', 'twentyten' ), '<span class="edit-link">', '</span>' ); ?>
                </div><!-- .entry-content -->
            </div><!-- #post-## -->
     <?php endwhile; ?>
```